# FIXED Div stays at the top but cuts off text with no scroll bars

Tags: css

I have some text that I display in a `div` with the following CSS:

```
.fixed-box {
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    width: 270px;
}
```

This is so that when I scroll it always shows on the top of the screen. However when there is a lot of text the div gets cut off, because the `position:fixed` prevents it from scrolling down with the page it's on.

I was going to switch to an `iframe`, but is this really the best way to go?

Comment: You could add a height attribute so if you have too much text you can make it fit on the screen.

Comment: The problem that you are describing is not in the CSS that you have posted. The code works perfectly fine for me: http://cssdesk.com/bwUhC. You need to ensure that you haven't set a `height` or `max-height` value for the div elsewhere in your CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add     `overflow:auto;` and set height property either to 100% or manually.
Here is code example [http://jsfiddle.net/7ZVb8/](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZVb8/2/)